# Does the src/ folder in PyPI packaging have a special meaning or is it only a convention?

Tags: python, packaging, pypi

I'm learning how to package Python projects for PyPI according to the tutorial (https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/). For the example project, they use the folder structure:

```
packaging_tutorial/
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── src/
│   └── example_package_YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── example.py
└── tests/
```

I am just wondering why the `src/` folder is needed? Does it serve a particular purpose? Could one instead include the package directly in the top folder? E.g. would

```
packaging_tutorial/
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── example_package_YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── example.py
└── tests/
```

have any disadvantages or cause complications?

Comment: You can either use src or not, both have advantages and disadvantages. Python packaging can be done with so many different ways, it has become a nightmare for beginners. You can read this article https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/ . I hope it helps

Comment: There is an interesting [blog post](https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/) about this topic; basically, using `src` prevents that when running tests from within the project directory, the package folder gets imported instead of the installed package (and tests should always run against installed packages). But in the end it's not a requirement but more of a convention/best practice. For example [`requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests) doesn't use `src` and they still manage to be a popular and successful project.

Comment: @a_guest I feel that your comment may qualify as an answer if extended a bit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an interesting [blog post](https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/) about this topic; basically, using `src` prevents that when running tests from within the project directory, the package source folder gets imported instead of the installed package (and tests should always run against installed packages, so that the situation is the same as for a user).

Consider the following example project where the name of the package under development is `mypkg`. It contains an `__init__.py` file and another `DATA.txt` non-code resource:

```
.
├── mypkg
│   ├── DATA.txt
│   └── __init__.py
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.cfg
└── test
    └── test_data.py
```

Here, `mypkg/__init__.py` accesses the `DATA.txt` resource and loads its content:

```py
from importlib.resources import read_text
  
data = read_text('mypkg', 'DATA.txt').strip()  # The content is 'foo'.
```

The script `test/test_data.py` checks that `mypkg.data` actually contains `'foo'`:

```py
import mypkg
  
def test():
    assert mypkg.data == 'foo'
```

Now, running [`coverage run -m pytest`](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/) from within the base directory gives the impression that everything is alright with the project:

```
$ coverage run -m pytest
[...]
test/test_data.py .                                             [100%]

========================== 1 passed in 0.01s ==========================
```

However, there's a subtle issue. Running `coverage run -m pytest` invokes [`pytest`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest/) via `python -m pytest`, i.e. using the [`-m`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) switch. This has a "side effect", as mentioned in the docs:

> [...] As with the `-c` option, the current directory will be added to the start of `sys.path`. [...]

This means that when importing `mypkg` in `test/test_data.py`, it didn't import the installed version but it imported the package from the source tree in `mypkg` instead.

Now, let's further assume that we forgot to include the `DATA.txt` resource in our project specification (after all, there is no [`MANIFEST.in`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/)). So this file is actually not included in the *installed* version of `mypkg` (installation e.g. via `python -m pip install .`). This is revealed by running `pytest` directly:

```
$ pytest
[...]
======================= short test summary info =======================
ERROR test/test_data.py - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file ...
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========================== 1 error in 0.13s ===========================
```

Hence, when using `coverage` the test passed despite the installation of `mypkg` being broken. The test didn't capture this as it was run against the source tree rather than the installed version. If we had used a `src` directory to contain the `mypkg` package, then adding the current working directory via `-m` would have caused no problems, as there is no package `mypkg` in the current working directory anymore.

But in the end, using `src` is not a requirement but more of a convention/best practice. For example [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests) doesn't use `src` and they still manage to be a popular and successful project.